# How to disable shadows of windows in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, macos-big-sur

By searching the solution to disable shadows in MacOS, I found an answer `defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true`

But it does not work in the latest MacOS - Big Sur

How do I disable shadows of windows in MacOS Big Sur?

Comment: This question better fits [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched for years for something that works. As I use an inverted screen, the shadow is bright white and drives me nuts. This is the only thing I've found that comes close to working: https://github.com/w0lfschild/winBuddy

It is a bit flaky and messes up firefox tabs and ms office

If someone finds a better solution, pls let me know

Comment: BTW some tools like iTerm2 *tries* to disable this, "
 /*! Disables shadows on all windows. */
 kCGSDebugOptionNoShadows = 0x4000,

" but apple decided at some point, no, everyone likes shadows. All the tools seem to try the same approach and hence they are all bust.

Answer (score 1):

Install MacForge (https://www.macenhance.com/macforge.html) and search for noShadows from the market (it's all free). I have tested on Big Sur and it works like a charm. See my examples below

[image: before]
[image: after]

PS: you will have to disable stuff like System Integraity Protection and Library Validatiion, as suggested as the startup of MacForge.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Big Sur does not allow you to do this.

Comment: this is the right answer tbh

Comment: if you can't do it without disabling SIP, then the general answer is that you can't do it. questions have an implicit "without disabling SIP" in them if you don't say up front that you're OK with disabling SIP just to get the little improvement.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the border and drop shadow by holding down the Option key while clicking. This lets you retain it when you want and disable it otherwise. The default macOS screen capture of a window includes a border and drop shadow (top), but you can easily change this for each capture or permanently (bottom). Click the green button by the question if you accept the answer and it helped you.

The information came from [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/3527415/how-to-get-rid-of-the-screenshot-drop-shadow-in-macos.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20remove%20the%20border,want%20and%20disable%20it%20otherwise.&text=The%20default%20macOS%20screen%20capture,capture%20or%20permanently%20(bottom).)

Comment: Your answer is just to disable shadows when capturing a screenshot.

Comment: @JimmyFarley: Right said.

Comment:  Not correct.

Comment: -1. Jimmy Farley's comment should be included in this answer, which is a highly partial answer. The original question is about permanently removing shadows all the time.